# MySQL select group by date, arithmetic, then sum results

Tags: mysql, case

I've got a table thats just three columns, ID, DATETIME, VALUE

Each DATETIME is from various samples during the day, from different meters.

I need to perform a math function on each value eg. (value * 60 * 10)/1000000 = new_value, and then group new_value by DATE(datetime), and sum the values for each date, and do this for a select group of ID's.

The result I need is each DATE, with its sum value of those meters.

I've tried:

```
SELECT date(sub_meter_data.date) as date, 
sum(CASE WHEN sub_meterID = '58984' OR '58985' OR '58986' OR '58987' THEN (((value*60)*10)/1000000) ELSE 0 END) as value
FROM `sub_meter_data` WHERE
date(sub_meter_data.date) > '2012-10-01'
GROUP BY date(sub_meter_data.date)
```

Here's some sample data:

```
sub_meterID       date           value
58984     2012-10-18 23:23:05.000   94.82643
58982     2012-10-18 23:28:52.000   97.43638
58984     2012-10-18 23:33:04.000   100.1923
58985     2012-10-18 23:43:01.000   97.93111
58984     2012-10-18 23:53:05.000   93.02759
58986     2012-10-19 00:03:03.000   88.29563
58984     2012-10-19 00:13:02.000   81.23074
58987     2012-10-19 00:23:07.000   86.37943
58984     2012-10-19 00:33:04.000   88.64834
```

Comment: And what is the problem in the query you tried? Any errors? Not what you want to get?

Comment: Could you pls provide some sample data with intended result for easier understanding?

Comment: The result is the sum of the values, and *then* the multiply/divide.  I want it to multiply and divide the values, then sum the result.

Comment: 1) No, your query does what you want: Each value is multiplied and divided and the results are summed. 2) That makes no difference because a*60*10/1000000 + b*60*10/1000000 = (a+b)*60*10/1000000. Please show your "wrong" results based on that sample data.

Comment: I'm not so sure again now.  Performing a select on each meter in the list, and using the same formula, does not give a corresponding result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below:

```
SELECT date(`date`), 
       sum(((value*60)*10)/1000000) as value
FROM `sub_meter_data` 
where date(sub_meter_data.date) > '2012-10-01' 
      and sub_meterID in('58984','58985','58986','58987')
group by date(`date`);
```

Comment: Yay!  Thanks sel, life-saver-you!